# Any reason why this substitution is not working- python

Tags: python

I am trying to insert "\n" when ever I am finding Google.

```
Google(12,AB12,XYZ,A2)
```

Note: the Parameters inside Google is dynamic.

What I have tried:

```
Str=re.sub(r"Google(.*)",r"Google(.*)\n",str)
```

Currently I am getting as:

```
Google(.*) followed by newline
```

What I want is:

```
Google(12,AB12,XYZ,A2) followed by newline
```

Comment: Why not just use `string=string+"\n"`

Comment: Sruthi I dont want to use string as the string parameters are generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitutions are not regular expressions, but a different pattern where you can use part of the original match, e.g.:

```
re.sub(r"Google(.*)", r"\g<0>\n")
```

Cf. http://www.regular-expressions.info/refreplacebackref.html for information about replacement placeholders.

**EDIT:** As for your perceived lack of »global« substitution: `re.sub` will actually replace all matches in the string, but your regex actually matches from `Google` to the end of the string. Something like the following should work a bit better:

```
re.sub(r"Google\((.*?)\)", r"\g<0>\n")
```

Here `.*?` is »lazy«, so it will only match as much as possible to make the rest of the regex match as well, in this case up to the first closing parenthesis (instead of the last, as with the greedy match).

Comment: Joey Thanks this worked for me. Got to know where I was wrong.

Comment: Hi @Perl, if you find that this answer solves your problem, we encourage you to press the green check mark on the left.

Comment: Sean Francis N. Ballais thanks for the advice. But it takes min 5 mins for the tick to turn green. so was waiting for that

Comment: Two occurences of such substring within a string is not substituted. I mean global substitution is not happening. Do i have to add something else for that?

Comment: @Perl, your `.*`is greedy and will actually match from `Google` to the very end of the string. I added some remarks.

Comment: @Joey Thank you so much. This is perfect for me. And thanks for explaining the concept as well

Comment: Can you please help me how to revert it back?
`re.sub(r"Google(.*)\n", r"\g<0>")`
This does not seem to work

Answer (score 1):

Use a backreference to capture the matched string:

```
import re
str = 'Google(1)Google(2)'
str = re.sub(r'Google\(.*?\)',r'\g<0>\n', str)
print(str);
```

Output:

```
Google(1)
Google(2)
```

Comment: `\0` should be `\1`. Also `()` should be around whole pattern to produce the output you have shown.

Comment: `re.sub(r"Google(.*)",r"\0\n","Google(12,AB12,XYZ,A2)")` gives me `\x00\n` on Python 3.

Comment: \g<0> is a backreference to the whole match.

Comment: In that case use a non-greedy match like r'Google\(.*?\)' as above.

Comment: Can you please help me how to revert it back? re.sub(r"Google(.*)\n", r"\g<0>") This does not seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

`google = "Google(12,AB12,XYZ,A2)"
googleWithNewLine = "{0}\n".format(google)
print(googleWithNewLine)`

Comment: I suppose that `str` is not simply `Google(12,AB12,XYZ,A2)` but a text with mixed content. Otherwise it would be trivial.

Comment: I am not sure either, but it was never mentioned that its is a complex object and not a string , per se. I took my liberties

Comment: Maxime Cheramy Yes thats a text with mixed content. Joey answer has helped. Thanks for this information too